# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'MapboxGL.StyleURL')

Tags: react-native, api, dictionary

I'm trying to integrate a map in my application but I have this error "TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'MapboxGL.StyleURL')", I have npm install "npm install @react-native-mapbox-gl/maps --save" I even tried with yarn but nothing changes, I'm using a jawg api.

token

```
MapboxGL.setAccessToken("my token");
```

part of code

```
        <View style={styles.mapcontainer}>
          <MapboxGL.MapView style={styles.map} />
        </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it's not too late.

Your error says that you did not set the attribute `styleURL` in your `<MapboxGL.MapView>` component.

A correct usage of this code should be

```js
<MapLibreGL.MapView
  style={styles.map}
  logoEnabled={false}
  attributionEnabled={true} // Required due to GTCs
  attributionPosition={{bottom: 8, left: 8}}
  styleURL={`https://api.jawg.io/styles/jawg-sunny.json?access-token=${accessToken}`}>
</MapLibreGL.MapView>
```

I hope this helps!